# Can not remove input checkbox completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

This is div

```
    <div id="current-menus-for-role-div">
    <h2>current for role</h2>
    <div class="list-group" id="current-menus-for-role-checkboxes">
        <!--        <input type="checkbox" /> Some label<br />-->
        <!--        <input type="checkbox" /> Some other label<br />-->
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="remove-menus-from-role-btn" class="btn btn-success">Sil</button>
</div>
```

I append checkboxes with this:

```
   var currentMenusForRoleCheckboxes = $('#current-menus-for-role-checkboxes');
         currentMenusForRoleCheckboxes.append('<input type="checkbox" id="'
                    + menu.id +
                    '"/> ' + menu.item + '<br />');
```

When the button is clicked, i want to remove checkboxes selected one by one:

```
        $('#remove-menus-from-role-btn').click(

            function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                function fireRemoveMenusFromRole() {

                    $('div#current-menus-for-role-div input[type=checkbox]')
                        .each(function () {
                            if ($(this).is(":checked") && !menuIdsToBeDeleted.includes(this.id)) {
                                console.log("selectedmenutoremove: " + this + " id:" + this.id);
                                menuIdsToBeDeleted.push(this.id);
                                console.log(" to menuIdsToBeDeleted added: " + menuIdsToBeDeleted);
debugger
                                $(this).remove();
                            }

                        });
                }

                fireRemoveMenusFromRole();
            });
```

but

```
     $(this).remove();
```

this only removes checkbox icon. Label stays there :(

I tried parent remove and this

```
             $(this).closest("list-group").remove();
```

but could not remove

Comment: wrap the input and text in a span or label and then append / remove that

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper `<label>` tag wrapping the `<input>` and wrap in a block element like  `<div>` instead of using `<br>` then remove the checkbox parents `<div>`

```
<div class="list-group" id="current-menus-for-role-checkboxes">
       <div><label><input type="checkbox" /> Some label</label></div>
       <div><label><input type="checkbox" /> Some other label</label></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
  $(this).nextUntil('input:checkbox').remove(); // remove every tag until the next checkbox
  $(this)[0].nextSibling.remove(); // remove the text next to the checkbox
  $(this).remove(); // remove the element itself
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/4kgqhn8f/